# How is SQL data is stored

Tags: sql, asp.net

How is SQL data is stored?  Each data type (nvarchar, numeric, varchar, etc.) will not let you change it to a "Double" with "Convert.Double()" after it is extracted using "SQLCommand".  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are not supposed to need to know how it's stored.

Comment: Show us how you are using `SqlCommand`... Probably the problem is there.

Answer (score 1):

> will not let you change it to a "Double" with "Convert.Double()" after
>   it is extracted using "SQLCommand"

You can convert it to `DOUBLE` type only iif the fetched value is of `double` type (or) a type (`INT` type say) which can be converted to `double` implicitly or explicitly. Cause for obvious reason you can't convert a string like *hello* to `double` as it's meanin less.

Comment: Which SQL type can you convert to Double (numeric, nvarchar, int) when the number is in the form 345.123456?

Comment: @losopha, all of them provided the value should be convertable. Example: say `nvarchar` column but the value is `hello` instead of `100.34` then how can it be converted?

Comment: What happens if the column was inputed from a XML table.  Could that affect the usability of a number?